# How can I correctly customize the separator inset betweet UITableViewCells in iOS 7?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, separator

When I create a UITableView and set custom separator insets, it uses the custom insets when there is no cell. Say there's room for 5 cells but only 3 are displayed, it shows a separator across the whole width of the tableview. In the remaining space below the cells it shows the custom insets (20 points from the left and from the right).

I've also set custom insets for the cell prototype, so I really don't understand why the separator shows across the total width of the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to set an empty footer. You can try this

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```